# javascript: Firebase app named already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I knew this problem is duplicated but i checked all possible solutions but no luck.

This is my code that i defined second firebase initializeApp to create new user without get kick.

```
let config = {
  apiKey: "//////////////////////////",
  authDomain: "//////////////////////////",
  databaseURL: "//////////////////////////",
};
let adminFirebase:any = this.appProvider.firebase.initializeApp(config,"adminFirebase");
adminFirebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email,this.user.password).then(user=> {
  this.user.newImage = null;
  this.user.password = null;
  this.user.type = "company";
  this.appProvider.afd.list("users").push(this.user).then(_=>{
    adminFirebase.auth().signOut().then(_=>{
      this.appProvider.showToast("Added successfully");
      this.appProvider.hideLoading();
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    });
  });
});
```

My code works one time only. then i face error message when try to add more users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is telling you that you're trying to create a second app with the same name "adminFirebase".  Don't call `initializeApp` twice with the same name - just remember the object that it returned the first time and reuse it.

Comment: exactly, but how to fix this problem to skip initializeApp for "adminFirebase" or delete it after adding user ?

Comment: You are right. I defined adminFirebase inside provide page to use initializeApp one time only and now my project works fine. thanks